# How to fill missing values when you have it in both columns? dictionary - map( ) method

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have this scenario. I’m in the process of learning. I'm cleaning a dataset. Now I have a problem
There are a lot of rows that have this issue

I have the key but not the name product. I have the name product but not the key.

```
prod_key    product
0   21.0    NaN
1   21.0    NaN
2   0.0 metal
3   35.0    NaN
4   22.0    NaN
5   0.0 wood
```

I know that the **key of metal is 24** and **the key of wood is 25**
The **product name that belongs to key 21 is plastic** and **the product name that belongs to key 22 is paper**

There are hundreds of rows with the same situation. So, rename each and everyone of them will take me a lot of time.

I created a dictionary and then I used the .map() method but I’m still unable to ‘merge’ or you can say ‘mix’ the missing values in both columns without removing the other column value.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extra dataframe and do merge two times

```py
lst = [
    ['metal',   24],
    ['wood',    25],
    ['plastic', 21],
    ['paper',   22]
]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['name', 'key'])


df1['product'].update(df1.merge(df2, left_on='prod_key', right_on='key', how='left')['name'])

df1['prod_key'].update(df1.merge(df2, left_on='product', right_on='name', how='left')['key'])
```

```
print(df2)

      name  key
0    metal   24
1     wood   25
2  plastic   21
3    paper   22


print(df1)

   prod_key  product
0      21.0  plastic
1      21.0  plastic
2      24.0    metal
3      35.0      NaN
4      22.0    paper
5      25.0     wood
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I spend a lot of time trying to figure it out, without a correct result. Your code is quite tricky I'm going to study it  so I can understand it.